# Find a sequence of positive functions with non-trivial properties in $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$ and in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I was asked to exhibit a sequence of positive functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ belonging to $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ such that:

- $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is strongly converging to $0$ in $L^1([-\pi,+\pi])$, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_n(x)\,dx = 0,$$
- $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is weakly convergent to $0$ in $L^2([-\pi,+\pi])$, i.e. $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\quad\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_n(x)\,e^{ikx}dx = 0,$$
- $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not strongly converging to $0$ in $L^2([-\pi,+\pi])$, i.e. $$\liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_n^2(x)\,dx>0.$$
  I tried to take $f_n(x)$ as the square of a Fourier series with $n$ terms, but cannot manage to control the coefficients in order to fulfill all the previous properties.

Comment: For the second one, do you want $f_k(x)$ instead of $f_n(x)$?

Comment: Your limit should be $n \to + \infty$ in the second bullet point.

Comment: @Umberto P.: You are right, it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Since the functions $f_n$ are nonnegative, the second condition is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n(n+1)} 1_{[{1 \over n+1}, {1 \over n}]}(x)+{1 \over n}$.

(Note that the second condition follows from the first by Hölder, since the
exponential term is bounded and 
$\|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_1 \|g\|_\infty$.)

Comment: I missed the simple fact you and Umberto P. pointed. Another possible choice is $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\min\left(\frac{1}{|x|},n\right),$$ since the $L^1$-norm is $O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right)$ and the $L^2$-norm is $4+O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to take
$$f_n(x) = a_n \, \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$$
with suitable chosen $a_n$.

Comment: $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ seems to work. It was simpler than I thought, thank you so much.

Comment: You should probably add a small term $\varepsilon_n > 0$ to ensure they are positive.